# How do I delete multiple lines in nano without affecting the clipboard?

Tags: shortcut-keys, nano

I can select all file by going to the 1st line <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, start marking the text by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, go to the last line by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

But there, I don't know which key to remove the selected text. Hit delete doesn't work for me but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to cut the text will destroy my clipboard.

So, what is the hotkey to delete selected text?

Comment: The short answer is that nano does not provide a way to delete blocks, just cut.

Comment: Nano cheatsheet https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/cheatsheet.html

Answer (score 189):

`nano` of course can delete blocks, see this [article](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2237914&seqNum=4)

1. use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> to mark the beginning of your block
2. move cursor with arrow keys to end of your block, the text will be highlighted.
3. use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to cut/delete block.

To paste the block to another place, move cursor to the position and the use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. You can paste the block as often as you want to.

Comment: Linux Mint seems to accept `CTRL`+`ALT`+`6` to mark the beginning of the block.

Comment: This is a superior answer

Comment: The shortcut for marking the beginning of the block is actually `CTRL` + `^`. So `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `6` might not be correct depending on your keyboard layout.

Comment: As asked, we seeks for the way that not affecting the clipboard. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 51):

*nano* does not support deleting a block of text, only cutting it (to the server's clipboard).

Instead, if you are using Putty, do the following:

1. Select the text you wish to **copy** to the clipboard with the mouse first -- this copies it to your *local clipboard* (i.e. Windows 7 clipboard), which *nano* can't touch:

   [image]
2. Then, select your block in *nano* and use `Ctrl-K` to delete it.
3. Finally, move your cursor to the position where you want to insert the text you copied in Step 1 (you can close *nano*, open another file, etc. too *as long as you don't select another block of text with the mouse*). **Right-click** to paste the copied text at the cursor position.

Comment: This doesn't work for long lines. The moment you see that $, the line will be truncated.

Comment: nano does support cutting of blocks Ctrl+Shift+6, highlight, Ctrl+k

Answer (score 22):

If you are trying to empty all of the lines.

A pretty elegant and simplest approach is from the bash-cli:

- `echo "" > filename.txt`
- `nano filename.txt`

Comment: This worked for me, Thank you :)

Answer (score 13):

```
CTRL SHIFT K
```

deletes current line, It can also be useful for quick editing. 
Thanks

Edit1:

In some of the putty streams, the following works too

```
CTRL K
```

Comment: Thank you alot, this is the answer!

Comment: `ctrl+shift+k` in more than one line add incrementally into internal clipboard (of nano), and only `ctrl+k`, stores only the latest text.

Answer (score 6):

To delete multiple block without overriding your clipboard, first mark the text with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (You will appear `Mark Set` then select the text using arrow keys) and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to delete selected text,deleted text won't appear in clipboard.

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, nano doesn't seem to have any way of bulk-deleting without clobbering the clipboard.

The safest thing to do while staying within the document is probably to paste your clipboard before deleting, then re-cut it again afterwards.

If you have a block of text already selected, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> will paste the clipboard text, including it in your selected block.  You can then unmark the pasted text and just cut your originally selected block.

These steps don't preserve your clipboard, exactly, but at least effectively perform a swap between your selection and the clipboard, allowing you to re-cut the lines you had in there before.

Answer (score 5):

In Nano

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> to set a mark
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> will delete all content in a file
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> will delete the current line at your cursor.

Answer (score 2):

You could open up a separate buffer to stash your clipboard in:

- Make sure "reading into separate buffer" is enabled (you can toggle this with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (without entering a filename), to open a blank file buffer
- Paste your current clipboard in there with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
- Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> to switch between open buffers

Comment: Thanks but that seems overkill the line delete need

Comment: Yeah, I agree.. To be honest, I'd probably recommend posting the issue as a bug report. Sadly they don't seem to have a section for feature requests, but there are existing reports with [Request] in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of nano (3.2+) now have this feature if you enable the `zap` option. Put `set zap` in your nanorc (or start nano with `-Z`/`--zap`), select the text your want to delete, and hit <kbd>⌫</kbd> to delete your selection without affecting the cutbuffer.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @saagarjha around version 3.2 of nano they introduced a `zap` command which allows you to delete text without affecting the cutbuffer.

> M-Del           Throw away the current line (or marked region)

To delete a line by itself use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> with the cursor on the line you want to delete.

To delete a block of text, first set the starting mark with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and select the text to be deleted and finally press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

To undo a delete, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>. To redo a delete, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>. For me redo didn't work until I disabled alt menu access keys in the preferences of my terminal emulator.

Comment: Will try alt-delete and pick yours as accepted if it's that simple confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

For me (on a mac) Control + K did what I wanted (deleted a full line)

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1324254/

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> (Sets the mark position) 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (Enter the lines nos to delete) 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (Delete the selection)

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl` + `T` (opens Command to execute tab)

`Ctrl` + `V` (Cut Till End)

Tested on Ubuntu Server

Comment: CTRL+V is page down